# ng update @angular/cli returning Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to upgrade my angular-cli from version 1.7.4 to version 8.3.8 using "ng update @angular/cli" command but I getting following error:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.8) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
```

I'm running under a proxy and I guess it is configured properly since NPM is working well. I'm upgrading the client in order to migrate an application from angular 5 to 6 (and then 6 to 7 and 7 to 8). I'm following the steps provided by the official angular website but I'm stuck on this step (upgrading the angular cli).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update your Angular CLI first

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/7.0.2#updating-angular-cli

Check this [issue & answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11896).

Comment: Thanks for answering... Updating as in the link it worked for me, I was following the instructions from this site: https://update.angular.io/#5.0:6.0